# allow single URL from a sentence in a UITextView

Tags: ios, ios7

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows. I have a `UItextview` with a sentence that has a URL within the sentience. I'm needing to be able to allow the only one `URL` can be added in the `UItextview`, at the same time the total `URL` is taken from single character that is presented within any sentence that is within a `NSString` so for example:

Let's say I had this `NSString` on `UItextView`:

```
NSString *samplestr = @"This is a sample of a http://google.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have look the following code

```
NSString *string = @"your string with url ";
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
    NSURL *url = [match URL];
    NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont ask extract the url, i need allow only one url and the whole url string taken into single character bro, can u do this

Comment: you are trying to allow the users to type only one url inside a `uitextView`. Is it?

Comment: yes and also i need the url string is only one character ex : NSLog(@"found URL: %@", url);the url string taken as only 1 character

Comment: I dont think so, is it much easier. Other case allow the user to type the string and filter the URl From the string and convert the URL to Char as `const char *cfilename=[stringobject UTF8String];`